# gcloud sql export support target uri as shared directory apart from cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I want to export cloud sql data to shared location accessible from GCP, does gcloud export support that ?

To export data we can use
gcloud sql export csv INSTANCE_NAME gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME 
--database=DATABASE_NAME 
--offload 
--query=SELECT_QUERY

in place of "gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME" if we can specify non cloud storage location something like file://<>/<> which is accessible from Cloud SQL, will it work ?

Answer (score 1):

> in place of "gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME" if we can specify non cloud
> storage location something like file://<>/<> which is accessible from
> Cloud SQL, will it work ?

No, the only scheme supported is **gs**.

If you could specify the URI **file://...** then that URI would represent a file within the Cloud SQL instance and that would be a security vulnerability.

The URI must be in this format:

```
gs://bucket/blob
```

[gcloud sql export sql](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/export/sql)

Comment: So, If i use file://path_on_cloud_sql_instance, it will work, right ?

Comment: No, it will not work. Please reread my answer.